# How to get text of element but excluding the sub-elements text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jquery-selectors, webdriver

I want to get the text of the element without including the text of its elements. I have tried getText(), but it returns text that includes all the child elements text.

In the following example: When I retrieved text from the first div, it returns text that includes all its subelements.

```
<div class="row”>
    <div class="col-lg-4 section”>
        <div class="col-md-12”>
            inseam 28 30 32
        </div> 
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 section”>
        <div class="col-md-13”>
            inseam 28 34 36
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how to do this using webdriver in java.

Thanks 
sean

Comment: Share the code written, that will help in understanding your question better.

Comment: Shoaib, I'm just trying to read to the text of the elements not including the sub-elements text.    List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.xpath("*"));   
   for ( WebElement e : el ) {
e.getText();}

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the same thing for a while, here's my solution for those who can specify a WebElement or a list of WebElements:

```
def remove_child_text_from_webelement(webelement):
    # Declaring the current text for this webelement
    current_text = webelement.text
    # Getting its childs elements in a list
    childs_list = webelement.find_elements_by_xpath('./*')
    # Manipulating text to remove child text from parents
    childrens_text_list = [child.text for child in childs_list]
    #return (childrens_text_list,type(childrens_text_list))
    for children_text in childrens_text_list:
        match_index = current_text.find(children_text)
        if match_index != -1:
            match_length = len(children_text)
            current_text = current_text[0:match_index] + current_text[match_index+match_length:]
    return current_text
```

Now you can do something like:

```
[remove_child_text_from_webelement(e) for e in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"person")]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

**`When I retrieved text from the first div with class 'row', it returns text that includes all its subelements.`**

- This happened because you **retrieved text from the parent div** and hence all the innerHTML/text of the child divs were retrieved along with them.

Below is the way to retrieve the necessary innerHTML/text only:

1- for **'inseam 28 30 32'**:

`String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12']")).getText();`

OR

`String text = driver.findElement(By.className("col-md-12")).getText();`

2- for **'inseam 28 34 36'**:

`String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-13']")).getText();`

OR

`String text = driver.findElement(By.className("col-md-13")).getText();`

Answer (score 0):

Not tried it specifically with Selenium, but with jQuery you can use `contents()` to get all elements *including raw text nodes*, filter by `nodeType` 3 (text nodes) and then take the `first`, in your example:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/p33gcfk2/1/

```
var text = $('.row').contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).first();
alert(text.text());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try to figure out how to run this jquery code with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to get the text of parent tag. If you want to get tag of particular child, you have to reach all the way there. You can take use of "nth-child" or "nth-of-type". For e.g in this case, if you want to have return this text "inseam 28 34 36".

The CSS selector will be "div.row div:nth-of-type(3)" or you can directly specify the div class "div.col-md-13"

You can refer to this article on more on selectors https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Comment: Shesh, I want to read the text of an element without including the subelements text.

Comment: Sean, can you please let me know what text you are actually trying to get from the above html code that you provided. In the above code, div.row will return text of all the elements as mentioned in my previous comment. Also, div.row itself doesn't have any text of its own. In mentioned code, there are only two elements that will return text that are div.col-md-12 = "inseam 28 30 32" and div.col-md-13 = "inseam 28 34 36".

Comment: Shesh, I'm trying to read the font and compare with some font for all the elements on the page. In many cases, element with text has multiple parent elements without any text,and the different font set than the text displayed. So, I want to remove the elements with no text from the comparision. But i'm not able to do that using getText() as it is returning text of all the child elements.

Comment: Sean, If i am not correct you want to test font size are equal for two text. If this is correct then this is wrong approach, you cannot get the font value by getText(). To test the font, you have to use getCSSValue() or take use of javascript executor.